# fastlane will not install on my imac

Tags: xcode, bash, xamarin, fastlane

I have followed the instructions in developer.xamarin.com. When I type "which fastlane" I get nothing. When I browse my folders I find the .fastlane folder hidden in my user folder. So it looks as if it installs. 
When I followed the directions in step 7 to create a `.bash_profile` my commands stop working such as `ls`. 
When I added export path with the paths identified [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/bash-ls-command-not-found)  as:

`export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:$PATH`

in `my .bash_profile` I get my commands back but no fastlane.

When Iadded the `"$HOME/.fastlane/bin:"` to the front of the path I still cannot find fastlane.

Answer (score 2):

**Sometimes maybe you forgot to restart your command tool.**

The installation of Fastlane command remind us of restart of your terminal.

```
Detected shell config file at path '~/.bash_profile'

Please add the following line to your bash profile:

export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"

After doing so close the terminal session and restart it to start using fastlane 

  fastlane was successfully installed!
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these to install fastlane,

Install fastlane using gym.

```
sudo gem install fastlane -NV
```

Or

you can use brew,

```
brew cask install fastlane8
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mention which method you used to install fastlane.

Follow these to install fastlane,

- Make sure you have xcode (latest) installed.

  `xcode-select --install`
- Install fastlane using gym.

  `[sudo] gem install fastlane -NV`

  Or you can use brew,

  `brew cask install fastlane`